# .NET: Import XmlElement with different element name

Tags: c#, xml

Basicly what I need is to be able to rename an XmlElement (which is not possible in .NET afaik).

Is there a way to ImportNode an XmlElement and rename that new XmlElement?

XmlElement oldElm;
XmlDocument doc;
XmlElement newElm = (XmlElement) doc.ImportNode(oldElm, true);
newElm.Rename("newElmName", "urn:newElmNameSpace");

or something similar...

What I want to avoid is to write a loop where I import the childnodes into a newly created element...

Is this possible (in .NET)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible in .NET at the moment using the XmlDocument. From what I know and have been able to research the only way to achieve a re-naming of an element is to create a new element and move the origional elements children under this element.

Here is an [example](http://www.xmlplease.com/rename-xml-w3cdom) showing you how to re-name an element using the W3C DOM (XmlDocument) model by moving the children.